# Catalyst - How to skip rendering a view

Tags: perl, catalyst

In one of my controllers, I'm doing some SSE async streaming (see [here](http://search.cpan.org/~jjnapiork/Catalyst-Runtime-5.90064/lib/Catalyst/Response.pm#%24res-%3Ewrite_fh)), and I have it working great in a barebones test project.  In the test project, I don't have a default view set, so it seems to just pass through - perfect!

Now I'm trying to put it into my existing larger project, however, I'm finding that forwarding it to any view messes it up and I can't figure out how to simply skip the rendering of a view.  Because I have a default view now, it refuses to just pass through.

I've blindly tried a few things: `$c->detach`, `$c->forward(undef)`, overriding the "**end**" method.  None have succeeded in skipping the view rendering - it always passes it on to my default view.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

Not super relevant, but the action in question:

```
sub time_server : Path('/events') {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
    $c->res->content_type('text/event-stream');
    $timer_model->( $c, $c->response->write_fh );
}
```

Comment: Are you using `Catalyst::Action::RenderView` to invoke your view or some other way?

Comment: I'm just setting the "default_view" config option, and it's passed on to that view automatically

Comment: The only thing `default_view` does is affect the default return value of `$c->view()`. It doesn't cause anything to be called. Normally the view would get run by `$c->forward($c->view)` or by giving your `end` action the `RenderView` ActionClass (which does the same exact thing).

Comment: Hmm, I don't have a custom end action - I'm just extending `Catalyst::Controller` so it must call `$c->forward($c->view)` somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Catalyst::Action::Renderview` has a small set of criteria it uses when deciding whether or not to call the view. It will skip running the view if:

- The request was a `HEAD` request.
- Something has already set `$c->response->body` to a defined value.
- `$c->response->status` is set to 204 ("No Content") or any 3xx (redirection).
- `$c->error` contains one or more errors and `$c->stash->{template}` hasn't been set (so that `finalize_error` can do its job instead).

Honestly this isn't the best possible arrangement, but what I would try in your situation is setting `$c->res->body("");` in your `time_server` action. An empty body won't write anything, and your headers are already finalized since you've called `write_fh`, but an empty string is still defined so it'll keep RenderView from doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution to force the function in default Catalyst controller response JSON type. You should change the content type to stream.
I hope it can help you.

```
sub my_function{
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
    
    my $payload = {
        "yourkey" => "backtooldschool",
        "yourkey2" => "2020"
    };
    my $result = encode_json($payload);

    $c->response->body($result);
    $c->response->content_type('application/json');
    $c->response->status(200);
}
```